# How can i get "root_key" from Hashicorp Vault server running?

Tags: node.js, hashicorp-vault

I'm beginner of Hashicorp Vault. I've worked it for 3 days and I'm in stuck.

So, my problem is I have a Hashicorp Vault server and I use `node-vault` to interact.

I have 2 clients (node-vault) to connect to Hashicorp Vault server.

When "Client 1" access to Hashicorp Vault server for the first time, Hashicorp Vault server will return the token for "client 1".

But, when I do the same thing with "client 2" for the second time. Hashicorp Vault produces an error: "Vault is already initialized".

So, how can I get a token for "client 2" from Hashicorp Vault server when it is initialized?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vault as your `node-vault`.

The problem is that you init your vault from `Client 1` and you try to do the same from `Client 2`, hence the error.

What you need to do is save the output from `Client 1` and then either

1. share the root key returned from `Client 1` to `Client 2` (BAD IDEA - dont do that)
2. create policies and distribute tokens to `Client 2`.

Comment: thanks for your help. So, should I init Vault Server from node-vault?